# Why does `Client.Send` returns nil err when status code is != 200

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using [sendgrid go library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go) to send an email from my go server with the following snippet:

```golang
    to := mail.NewEmail("", req.ToEmail)
    from := mail.NewEmail("", "xxx@gmail.com")      // redacted
    m := mail.NewV3MailInit(from, "", to)
    m.SetTemplateID("d-xxxxx")                      // redacted
    client := sendgrid.NewSendClient(os.Getenv("SENDGRID_API_KEY"))
    resp, err := client.Send(m)
    if err != nil {
      log.Printf("failed to send email to %s: %v\n", req.ToEmail, err)
    }
```

However, when I didn't set the SENDGRID_API_KEY env var, the `err` was still nil (and the response was as following:

```
{
  StatusCode:401 
  Body:{"errors":[{"message":"The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked","field":null,"help":null}]} 
  Headers:map[Access-Control-Allow-Headers:[Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl] Access-Control-Allow-Methods:[POST] Access-Control-Allow-Origin:[https://sendgrid.api-docs.io] Access-Control-Max-Age:[600] Connection:[keep-alive] Content-Length:[116] Content-Type:[application/json] Date:[Mon, 05 Jul 2021 19:15:31 GMT] Server:[nginx] Strict-Transport-Security:[max-age=600; includeSubDomains] X-No-Cors-Reason:[https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html]]}
```

I was blindly thinking that `err` should be set to something something non-nil, but I guess I need to look at status code in the response as well. Is there a quick way to check if the response returned is `OK` ?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

I'm not a Go developer, so I might be wrong here, but I think I know what's going on in general here.

The [SendGrid Go client](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go) uses the [SendGrid REST client](https://github.com/sendgrid/rest) which ultimately calls on [Go's standard lib HTTP client](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/). The HTTP docs, under the [`Get` method](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Get), say:

> An error is returned if there were too many redirects or if there was an HTTP protocol error. A non-2xx response doesn't cause an error. Any returned error will be of type *url.Error. The url.Error value's Timeout method will report true if request timed out or was canceled.

An HTTP request that returns a result is a successful request, even if the result is not something you wanted. An HTTP request that doesn't return a result, like a connection error or too many redirects, will return an error.

According to the [SendGrid API docs](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/mail-send/v3-mail-send) you should be looking for a `202` response status code to indicate a successful API request.